# Is there a bug with Worklight on IE 10?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've been working with a business partner to get an insurance app working on a Windows 8 tablet and have come across some interesting behavior that I can't explain.

I have managed to recreate the problem using a very simple use case and it appears to fail in the browser as well as when deployed as an app.

To re-create

1. Create a simple WL Hello World app with no JavaScript libraries
2. Deploy it to the development server
3. Open up an IE 10 browser and launch the WL Console.
4. Run this app using "Preview as Common Resources" and it should work fine (showing the default Hello Worklight)
5. click F12 to launch the IE debugger and then refresh the browser, click on the show console button to verify there were no errors
6. Add a `WL.Client.connect(...)` call into the `wlCommonInit` method

   ...

   ```
   WL.Client.connect({ 

       onSuccess: function(data) {
           console.log("connection Successful");
       },
       onFailure: function(err) {
           console.log("Connection FAILED: " + JSON.stringify(err) );
       }
   });
   ```
7. Save and re-run the app and it fails with an InvalidStateError (verify with F12 debugger)
8. Open up either a Chrome or Firefox browser to the WL Console page and click the "Preview as Common Resources" and open the developer tools for either and the console shows the connect call succeeding.

Is this a known problem or is there something that I've missed?

The ultimate goal is to deliver a Windows 8.1 tablet app however every time we tried to run the app it failed with this error.  After some debugging I thought maybe it has something to do with the OS and tried to replicate it in just the browser with minimum code.

Through testing I've found that the basic Hello Worklight app with a `WL.Client.connect()` fails on IE but works on other browsers.

So I'm thinking if I get it working in IE browser, then that fix will be good for the tablet app as well.

Any pointers or guidance would be appreciated.

Note I am using WL v6.2 (6.2.0.00-20140915-1601) 
Tested on Windows 7   - IE 10.0.9200.17089
Tested on Windows 8.1 - IE 11.0.9600.16663

The error I get is

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
   File: index.html
   wlclient init started
   before: initOptions.onSuccess
   Request [/Connect/apps/services/api/Connect/common/init]
   console.trace()
   at __log (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:4882:31)
   at Anonymous function (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:5240:7)
   at createRequestHeaders (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:3200:17)
   at sendRequest (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:3266:18)
   at initialize (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:3172:17)
   at klass (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:524:4)
   at sendInitRequest (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:7870:5)
   at connect (http://192.168.80.167:10080/Connect/apps/services/preview/Connect/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js:7879:3)
   SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError
   File: worklight.js, Line: 1055, Column: 3
   Uncaught Exception: InvalidStateError at (compiled_code):1055
```

Comment: And your Worklight version is...?

Comment: Is this only happening on IE 10 ? Did you try IE 11?

Comment: yes I tried in on IE10 (Windows 7) and IE11 (Windows 8.1)

Comment: OK I'll raise a PMR for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, this problem was resolved by moving to a newer fixpack release v6.2.0.00-20141002

Comment: Thanks @Marvin. I tested it on my home machine running Window 7 and IE11. I tested it on three different versions of Worklight and all worked well without any issue. I tested on WL 5.0.6, WL 6.1 and WL 6.2. I had similar issue in my office machine running Win 8.1 & IE11 so I think your mentioned fix pack would solve it as well.